# Slow Query Execution joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
Parts
id int (idx)
partnumber varchar (idx)
accountnumber (idx)
enabled
```

Sample data:
[image: Parts]

```
RefUserGroup
id int (idx)
value varchar (idx)
```

Sample Data:
[image: user group]

```
Pdf < has about 15 columns I will list ones I am interested 
in currently over 300,000's rows
id int (idx)
accountnumber varchar (idx)
customername varchar (idx)
```

Sample Data: [image: pdf]

```
Ref_UserGroup_Pdf
id
groupid FK (idx)
partsnumber (idx)
enable (idx)
```

Sample Data:
[image: ref_user_group_pdf]

**Query:** This takes around 47secs- 97 secs to return data.

```
SELECT p.partsnumber
,rug.`value` AS `group`
,pd.customername AS customer
FROM ref_groupid_to_pdf rgp
INNER JOIN ref_user_group rug ON rug.id = rgp.groupid
INNER JOIN parts p on rgp.partsnumber = p.partsnumber
LEFT JOIN pdf pd on p.accountnumber= pd.accountnumber 
WHERE rug.groupid = 2
AND rug.groupid <> 1
ORDER BY customer;
```

Can anyone point in the right direction on how to optimize this query? I am aware normally we put indexs on one, or more columns but for this I put index on every column that but even then it is really slow.

When the query joins on to the pdf table it becomes very slow.

Update Explain:
[image: explain]

Updated Query based on suggestions:

```
SELECT p.partsnumber
,rug.`value` AS `group`
,pd.customername AS customer
FROM ref_groupid_to_pdfid rgp
INNER JOIN ref_user_group_pdf rug ON rug.groupid = rgp.groupid
INNER JOIN parts p on rgp.partsnumber = p.partsnumber
INNER JOIN pdf_load pd on p.accountnumber = pd.accountnumber 
WHERE rug.id = 2
GROUP BY rgp.partsnumber;
```

Comment: What does `explain select ....` of your query says ?

Comment: I will post one second.

Comment: @Harry Where is `igroupid ` from~?

Comment: Hi, this an input parameter in the stored procedure. @Matt

Comment: How long does it take without the line `rug.groupid = igroupid ` or if you run it with a specified parameter e.g. `rug.groupid = '1'`

Comment: I just ran the query without the rug.groupid = igroupid and it has taken 55.178s, however I need this in the query because every group is assigned a parts number and that parts number is assigned an account number that they are allowed to see.

Comment: Also the two where clauses are pointless, you only need one if `WHERE rug.groupid = 2` then ` AND rug.groupid <> 1` is already redundant and not needed.

Comment: Hi, I understand but i require that because two group may have access to the same parts number hence the check for rug.groupid <> 1. is it still invalid?

Comment: If `igroupid` is a parameter, then it is either <>1 (and the second clause is redundant) or it is =1, and then the query would return nothing. Is this the desired result?

Comment: It is a parameter, I will never have the group id = 1. I see, yes then it is redundant i can take that out. @Andre451

Comment: Is it faster if you remove `ORDER BY customer`? You have a `LEFT JOIN pdf` so you expect empty `pd` rows, but you sort by `pd.customername`, that seems odd.

Comment: if I use inner join it does not return all pdf matching the account number for some reason. I tried it with a left join and it returns them. I have tried the query now without rug.groupid <> 1 and removed order by pd.customername and it is now taking 48.420s@Andre451 You are correct it does need to be an inner join btw.

Comment: Without the join to pdf table, the query is very quick. 0.060s. @Andre451 but joining on to this table causes it to slow.

Comment: Is it faster if you usee INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN? Also: *"if I use inner join it does not return all pdf matching the account number for some reason."* should make your alarm bell go DING DING, and you should try to figure out this problem.

Comment: No the result from the inner join is correct, I just checked this since your last comment. It now returns at 46.552s with an inner join. @Andre451

Comment: Ok. I guess a JOIN on varchar columns is inherently worse than on INT columns, but if both are indexed, it shouldn't be that bad. I'm afraid I'm out, but you should update the query in your question. **Edit** and please denote the primary keys in your tables.

Comment: thanks for your effort!! @Andre451

Comment: Why do you need the `GROUP BY rgp.epartsnumber;` on the second query? I always find this sintax of mysql (allow a group without an aggregate odd) since the sql ansi doesn't allow this.

Comment: Because I only ever need one parts number returned, if group by is not used I will get 100s of duplicate data for parts number

Comment: I don't understand that query. First of all the table names don't match the ones explained. But most of all, I too fail to see what the GROUP BY clause is meant to do. You group by `epartsnumber`, so you expect to find several records per `epartsnumber`, but want to aggregate to get only *one* result row per `epartsnumber`. But you don't use any aggregate functions (such as MIN or MAX). So you say: Give me one of the epartsnumber's rug-values and one of its customers. Don't you care *which*? Or can there be only one? Then you should use DISTINCT rather than GROUP BY.

Comment: thanks @ThorstenKettner I have updated the query in the question to match the ones explained. I see your point, the select should contain DISTINCT and not group by. There can only be one, for this scenario I don't care which one.

Comment: Also, your explain doesn't show the pdf table where is it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos ref "p" in the screen shot?

Comment: @Harry `p` is for parts table? Am I mistake?

Comment: Thank you. It is very strange to find the customer name in the pdf table. I would have expected it to be in a customer table. An account number in the pdf table can occur more than once, right? So I can find different cutomer names for one part. But you don't care and are satisfied with any one of the names. Yes?

Comment: yes you are mistaken, the screen shot represents my data on my machine. for the purposes of this question. I have renamed the tables so p is actually pdf table.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am working with the given tables and data unfortunately these were designed way before my time... @ThorstenKettner

Comment: And I can only find one record per partsnumber and groupid in Ref_UserGroup_Pdf?

Comment: Yes that is correct. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: I raised the exact point with my seniors but however I don't think they will be changing the table structure anytime soon... @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look up the customer name in a subquery. After all a part can have many entries in the pdf table, but you are always only interested in finding one such record arbitrarily. So pick that record with a LIMIT 1 query.

```
select
  prt.partsnumber,
  grp.value as `group`,
  (
    select customername 
    from pdf
    where pdf.accountnumber = prt.accountnumber
    limit 1
  ) as customer
from parts prt
join ref_usergroup_pdf ref on ref.partsnumber = prt.partsnumber
join refusergroup grp on grp.id = ref.groupid
where ref.id = 2;
```

Same query with parts table in the subquery instead. Choose whichever you like better:

```
select
  ref.partsnumber,
  grp.value,
  (
    select pdf.customername 
    from pdf
    where pdf.accountnumber = 
    (
      select prt.accountnumber
      from parts prt
      where prt.partsnumber = ref.partsnumber
    )
    limit 1
  ) as customer
from ref_usergroup_pdf ref
join refusergroup grp on grp.id = ref.groupid
where ref.id = 2;
```

As you have an index on `pdf(accountnumber)`, lookup should be pretty fast. It would be even faster if you had a composite index on `pdf(accountnumber,customername)`, as then you would gain all data needed from the index alone and the table wouldn't have to be read at all.

Comment: Thank you, can I just point out, ref.value does not exist in ref_usergroup_pdf table... do we require a join on RefUserGroup?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right. I've edited my answer accordingly and also added an alternative query doing exactly the same, only differently written.

Comment: ok, to test your query i removed re normalized the table and run your query wow, 0.70s!! genius, could you just explain what you have done here so I can understand it in more detail?

Comment: I guess I explained that more or less: Rather than joining *all* PDFs, only to remove most of them later by data aggregation, I only grab *one* PDF per part number. Thus I don't have a huge intermediate result set that I need to examine, but only select what's really needed.

Comment: can this approach be used for lets say, if i wanted to find a pdf.customername = somename and groupid?

Comment: You could easily put the condition on the customer name in the WHERE clause in the subquery (before limit1) to get this one customer name or none. If you only wanted to find PDFs for a customer and groupid, you'd probably rather write another query on PDF using an EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery and join the pdf table in the outer query.

```
SELECT n.partsnumber, n.group, pd.customername AS customer
FROM (SELECT p.partsnumber,rug.`value` AS `group`,p.accountnumber
    FROM ref_groupid_to_pdf rgp
    INNER JOIN ref_user_group rug ON rug.id = rgp.groupid
    INNER JOIN parts p on rgp.partsnumber = p.partsnumber
    WHERE rug.groupid = 2
    AND rug.groupid <> 1) n
LEFT JOIN pdf pd on n.accountnumber= pd.accountnumber ORDER BY customer;
```

Comment: thanks, I get the following error [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'customer' in 'order clause'

Comment: Sorry, move order by customer to outer query as well. I'll update my answer

Comment: If you need the group by clause, put that in the inner query before ") n"

Comment: How well does it perform if you run it without the order by?

Answer (score 0):

Use **straight_join** to reduce your query time:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN p.partsnumber
,rug.`value` AS `group`
,pd.customername AS customer
FROM ref_groupid_to_pdf rgp
INNER JOIN ref_user_group rug ON rug.id = rgp.groupid
INNER JOIN parts p on rgp.partsnumber = p.partsnumber
LEFT JOIN pdf pd on p.accountnumber= pd.accountnumber 
WHERE rug.groupid = 2
AND rug.groupid <> 1
ORDER BY customer;
```

Comment: Ok, Then try to give indexing on id,groupid,partsnumber,accountnumber.

Comment: If you have used indexing then please try once with FORCE INDEX. It will be definitely useful in your query.

Comment: thanks, I have tried this even then it does not make much difference in the execution time.