# DataRow.IsNull() does not return return correctly vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

**UPDATE:**
Just looking at the debugger and it tells me that the row is not null. 
[image: Debugger]

I am using DataRow.IsNull method to check if the row is null. Now if the row is null, then I am required to put in a default string, otherwise return the value in the row.

However, this does not seem to be working as expected? Am I missing something?

**Problem:**
It only places a default string for some rows and not others.

I am not sure if I have understood this process correctly? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Please note, a `DataSet` is return from the database and I loop through this for each row.

**Code:**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                                    Dim row = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)
                                    Dim obj As Foo = New Foo
With 
            {.FooAccNum = If(row.IsNull("accnum"), "Not Set", row.Field(Of String)("accnum")),
             .FooPartsNumber = If(row.IsNull("partsnumber"), "Not Set", row.Field(Of String)("partsnumber")),
             .FooGroup = If(row.IsNull("group"), "", row.Field(Of String)("group")),
             .FooCustomer = If(row.IsNull("customer"), "No record exists", row.Field(Of String)
            ("customer"))
FooList.Add(obj )
Next
```

**DataSet Returned:**
[image: DataSet]

As you can see, customer column is empty.

**View:**
[image: Grid]

As you can see in my grid view however, it does not set some of the row value for customer to **"No record exists"**. Why is this?

Comment: Could it be that these values are empty strings and not nulls? They would appear the same on the UI, but fail the IsNull check

Comment: some may be empty, any tips on how to capture null and if string is empty within my method?

Comment: Btw, you can do that also in your query. Then you dont need to loop the table again. `SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF('', Customer),'No record exists') AS Customer, ... FROM .....`

Comment: @TimSchmelter here is the query I am running, can it be achieved in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869004/slow-query-execution-joining-multiple-tables/33871205?noredirect=1#comment55535384_33871205

Comment: @harry: i have edited my comment. Maybe it would be good to update your table: `UPDATE tableName SET Customer = NULL WHERE Customer = ''` and to fix the code which inserts wrong values.

Comment: I think I will do that. thanks @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the case that these values are not null but just empty strings - then they would appear the same on the UI but fail the `IsNull` check. Additional value check should help you deal with them:

```
.FooCustomer = If(row.IsNull("customer") Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field(Of String)("customer")), 
                  "No record exists",
                  row.Field(Of String)("customer")
```

Comment: aah I see, I was not sure you could do this within the object initialization. Thanks!